# Using isdate() in VBA to remove string text in date field

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to clean up a data dump from a database. I have Some of the fields are dates and situation is some were entered incorrectly with dates missing and etc. For example: when the day wasn't known and written as 12/??/1952.  I am trying to weed out all the dates that are really strings.  Here is the code:

```
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long
Dim date_valid As Date
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

Set r = Range("H2:H" & LastRow)

mynumber = 1
For Each cell In r
    date_valid = cell.Value
    If isDate(date_valid) Then
        cell.Value = date_valid
        mynumber = mynumber + 1
        Debug.Print mynumber + 1
    Else
       cell.Value = " "//trying to save the nondate cell values as blank, putting in 12:00 am
        mynumber = mynumber + 1
        Debug.Print mynumber + 1
    End If
Next
```

The Debug.Print is there to help me figure out what line is causing the problem.

Error Message when it encounters a text field

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Any help you can provide is extremely appreciated.

Comment: at which line are you getting this error ? what do you want to do with theses dates ? delete them ? ignore ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  Dim date_valid As Date
>  date_valid = cell.Value
> ```

Type mismatch when `cell.value` is not a valid date. To fix it, declare `date_valid` as string.

```
Dim date_valid As String
...
date_valid = cell.Value
If isDate(date_valid) Then...
```